# How to compare two schema in Databricks notebook in python

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm going to ingest data using databricks notebook. I want to validate the schema of the data ingested against what I'm expecting the schema of these data to be.

So basically I have:

```
    validation_schema = StructType([
      StructField("a", StringType(), True),
      StructField("b", IntegerType(), False),
      StructField("c", StringType(), False),
      StructField("d", StringType(), False)
    ])

    data_ingested_good = [("foo",1,"blabla","36636"),
     ("foo",2,"booboo","40288"),
     ("bar",3,"fafa","42114"),
     ("bar",4,"jojo","39192"),
     ("baz",5,"jiji","32432")
    ]

    data_ingested_bad = [("foo","1","blabla","36636"),
     ("foo","2","booboo","40288"),
     ("bar","3","fafa","42114"),
     ("bar","4","jojo","39192"),
     ("baz","5","jiji","32432")
    ]
     
    data_ingested_good.printSchema()
    data_ingested_bad.printSchema()
    validation_schema.printSchema()
```

I've seen similar questions but answers are always in scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's really depends on your exact requirements & complexities of schemas that you want to compare - for example, ignore nullability flag vs. taking it into account, order of columns, support for maps/structs/arrays, etc.  Also, do you want to see difference or just a flag if schemas are matching or not.

In the simplest case it could be as simple as following - just compare string representations of schemas:

```py
def compare_schemas(df1, df2):
  return df1.schema.simpleString() == df2.schema.simpleString()
```

I personally would recommend to take an existing library, like [Chispa](https://github.com/MrPowers/chispa) that has more advanced schema comparison functions - you can tune checks, it will show differences, etc.  After installation (you can just do `%pip install chispa`) - this will throw an exception if schemas are different:

```py
from chispa.schema_comparer import assert_schema_equality

assert_schema_equality(df1.schema, df2.schema)
```

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed a complicated questions. and I was not sure how to formulate it. However I think that `simpleString()` is already a good answer to what I was asking at a first basic level.

Answer (score 2):

another method , you can find the difference based on the simple python `list` comparisons .

```
dept = [("Finance",10), 
        ("Marketing",20), 
        ("Sales",30), 
        ("IT",40) 
      ]
deptColumns = ["dept_name","dept_id"]

dept1 = [("Finance",10,'999'), 
        ("Marketing",20,'999'), 
        ("Sales",30,'999'), 
        ("IT",40,'999') 
      ]
deptColumns1 = ["dept_name","dept_id","extracol"]

deptDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=dept, schema = deptColumns)
dept1DF = spark.createDataFrame(data=dept1, schema = deptColumns1)
deptDF_columns=deptDF.schema.names
dept1DF_columns=dept1DF.schema.names

list_difference = []
for item in dept1DF_columns:
  if item not in deptDF_columns:
     list_difference.append(item)

print(list_difference)
```

**Screen print :**

[image]

Comment: It won't find difference if deptDF has more columns than dept1DF